# One controller, two edit actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I want to try having two different edit actions:

- one with nested form (`edit`)
- one without (`editclean`)

How can I render an edit action with a different method?

My `courses_controller.rb`:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @course = Course.new
  end

  def edit # <<<< edit nested
    @course.events.build
  end

  def editclean # <<<< edit only course
  end

  def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.update(course_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @course }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end

    def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:name, events_attributes: [:id, :starts_at])
    end
end
```

Comment: I've edited your question because you terminology was a bit mixed up. In the above code you have one *controller*, the class named CoursesController. Within that controller you have several different *methods*: `new`, `edit`, `editclean`, etc. In Rails we call methods that handle requests *actions* (the methods `set_course` and `course_params` are not actions). With that in mind, I've replaced "controller" with "action" in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few simple changes to make.  First, in your `routes.rb` file, you need to add the new route.  The easiest way is this:

```
resources :courses do
  member do
    get "editclean"
  end
end
```

This will add an "editclean" route and automatically `editclean` action in your controller.

In the controller, you have the add the `editclean` action to your before_action handler:

```
before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :editclean, :update, :destroy]
```

You also have to create the view file `editclean.html.erb`.  Your `edit` action probably shares a `_form.html.erb` partial with the `new` action.  You can either add conditionals to this partial or copy the relevant bits to the new view file.  Here's what your new view might look like:

```
<h2>Edit (clean) Course</h2>

<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :start_date, "Start Date" %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_date %>

  <%= f.label :end_date, "End Date" %>
  <%= f.text_field :end_date %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this will re-use the existing `update` action to save the fields.  If you want special behavior (avoiding some data checks), you might want to implement an alternative action, but the basic `update` action frequently works exactly as expected.

When you link to this you can use the route helper that was automatically created for you, like so:

```
<%= link_to "Edit (clean)", editclean_course_path(@course) %>
```

And that's about all there is to adding a new action.

Comment: I updated the routes, added the before_action, created the view and a link to it (actually `course_editclean_path(@course` ), but when I go to localhost:3000/courses/1/editclean it gives error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CoursesController#editclean Couldn't find Course without an ID @course = Course.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Does your database have a record with `id` = 1?  Can you go to the `edit` action with that id?  Note that the `set_course` private method shared by all of the actions is what retrieves the course from the database.  If it's broken for `editclean`, it's broken for all of them.  If you try a route for an `id` that you do have in your database, you should see that it works.

Comment: It looks like in the routes I have `/courses/:course_id/editclean(.:format)` whereas in normal edit it is `/courses/:id/edit(.:format)` - and it can not find column course_id. Any Ideas how to pass `id` instead of `course_id`?

Comment: I just updated the definition of the route.  I added a `member do` block, which should take care of that naming problem.  Try that and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options:

1. Give the new endpoint a different method name (i.e. `edit2`) and a new route.
2. Write the new code in a helper method (i.e. a model or in application controller) and change the code of your original `edit` action to run the new code if some condition is met.
   For example, I might check if `params[:edit_type].eql?("edit2")` and call the new edit logic (i.e. `def edit2`, defined in `application_controller`) from the original `edit` action.